# Windows 10 Error: FileNotFoundError: The System cannot find the file specified subprocess while executing an .exe

Tags: python, error-handling, exe

I get an error every time i want to start a exe build python. I cant change the code because its an exe.

The full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "boltchecker.py", line 6897, in <module>
File "boltchecker.py", line 4819, in __init__
File "subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
File "subprocess.py", line 489, in run
File "subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
File "subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[18104] Failed to execute script boltchecker
```

I hope someone can help me with this :)

Comment: what is the code you used to get the error`?

Comment: Its an exe for an account checker, i won it in a giveaway and everyone can open it except me. I dont got the source code tho

Comment: looks like a bug. Probably others have some executable to call or some file to manipulate

Comment: If this executable was built with pyinstaller or such, you can reverse-engineer it and get the code out. I'm not going to provide support for it here, but [I've built a tool for doing exactly that myself](https://github.com/charles-dyfis-net/pydeinstaller).

Comment: Yeah thats what i thought, other people can execute the exact same file, and it works.

Comment: See link edited into the earlier comment.

Comment: ...as for the immediate error, a lot of the time that kind of thing stems from a DLL dependency or such not being included. Once you've got the program decompiled you should be able to figure out what it's looking for easily enough. :)

Comment: Alright, thank you very much for your time!